# Powershell Get-Eventlog Filter by Time

Tags: powershell

I'm running Windows 2003 and I want to get a list of events at a specific time...after 12:06 pm. How can I get only those events at that time? I've tried this:

```
powershell get-eventlog application -after "3/15/2013 12:06:00 pm"
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
Cannot bind parameter 'InstanceId....
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this works:

```
 powershell -command  "get-eventlog application -after ([datetime]'3/15/2013 12:06:00 pm')"
```